# JavaScript Object.hasOwnProperty() issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is a document from mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11827eec69860e24519415"),
    "cardNumber" : "4519021475877785",
    "accounts" : [ 
        {        
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c10975d58fdf013e803e5da"),
            "currency" : "CAD"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the account from it: `account = data.accounts[0]`.

I can get the value of `currency` of this account: `currency = account.currency`

In my opinion, I think the account in JavaScript is an object.

So, `account.hasOwnProperty('currency')` should be `true`.

But it is `false` when I run my code....

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Are you using mongoose as your ORM, or are you directly using the mongodb package on npm?

Comment: I am using mongoose package to fetch data from mongodb

Comment: I think the problem is that you pick a wrong item. I tried do like you and it gives me true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object Mongoose gives you as the result of your query is not a plain-old JS object. It is a Document object (that class is defined in Mongoose) that holds the data somewhere else (possibly in its prototype chain), which is why hasOwnProperty returns false.

If you want to get your hands on an object that does contain the data fields as own properties, you can call the toObject() method of the Document object. Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)